# Tomcat7 busy error port

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

[Tomcat error](http://postimg.org/image/lgss1sxmt/)

I keep getting this error when trying to run a page on my tomcat7 server from eclipse. I have tried turning off windows fire wall and anti virus software. There are no other programs or services using the same ports which I have checked through using the command line. I have also tried changing the port number.

Help would be appreciated thanks Aidan.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat by default uses ports 8005, 8009 and 8080 - they're displayed on the error message. With that error message, I'm afraid, you're wrong: Something is running on any one of those ports, so that you can't start a second process binding to the same port.

You can change tomcat's port in server.xml (locate all occurrences of the port numbers) or (maybe, depending on the plugins you installed) in eclipse's server settings. Again - change them, for example by adding 1 to each port.

It might be that a tomcat process that you started earlier is still running. It might be that some software comes with an admin UI - I've seen several products coming with an administrative UI running on port 8080. Try to connect to http://localhost:8080/ and see if it's obvious what's running there (or if 8080 is the port that the error message is complaining about - it might be one of the others)